# Contentful + Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services, contentful

Hi i'm trying to use Contentful together with Angular2 using the contentful delivery API

i can get specific data for example

Contentful.service.ts

```
HomePage() {              
    return this.http
        .get('https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/PRIVATE/entries?access_token=PRIVATE&sys.id=PRIVATE')
        .map((res:Response) => res.json());    /* map response to var */  
}
```

homepage.component.ts

```
export class Home {

pagename: string;

    ngOnInit() {

        this.http.HomePage()
           .subscribe( 
               data => {
                       this.pagename = data.items[0].fields.pageName;
               }
          );
    }
 }
```

But if i have multiple items i would need to declare each data.item as a string which would get very long winded. And then if i decided to add a new field to a content type this might be added in the middle of the array, thus breaking the current bindings i have and would require updating them all again.

i've seen another repo where they use in the template the architecture i'm looking for and i know is the correct way of doing what i need to do.

e.g. homepage.template.html

```
<ul contentful-entries="'content_type=dog&limit=10'">
  <li ng-repeat="dog in $contentfulEntries.items">
    {{ dog.fields.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

which would mean there is no risk of the array breaking and tbh structures the code for scale and adding to it. But the repo where I've seen this

[Exmaple Repo by jvandemo](https://github.com/jvandemo/angular-contentful/blob/b28c02e306a3c11aeb71d2a948fd1948307d0a61/examples/how-to-use-the-directives/index.html)

is written in AngularJS V1 and i'm unsure of how to get this working in Angular2.. I'm still learning and i feel if someone could point me in the correct direction and example i could go forth and conquer this project!

ideally an example component and service. Am i also assuming that the Contentful SDK needs to be applied?

Also there is the issue of the link relationships (how contentful recommends building large content entries).

Contentful will list the fields in Items with the linked relationship to the content within the field with that ID and content. and any Assets for that Item will be put into Includes/Assets

Eg

```
 {
  "sys": {
      "type": "Array"
  },
  "total": 1,
  "skip": 0,
  "limit": 100,
  "items": [
     {
        "sys": {
            "space": {
            "sys": {
            "type": "Link",
            "linkType": "Space",
            "id": "1ST_UNIQUE_ID"
        }
    },
    "id": "2ND_UNIQUE_ID",
    "type": "Entry",
    "createdAt": "2016-07-14T16:30:12.787Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-07-14T16:30:12.787Z",
    "revision": 1,
    "contentType": {
      "sys": {
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "ContentType",
        "id": "pressRelease"
      }
    },
    "locale": "en-US"
  },
  "fields": {
    "title": "Title of Review",
    "excerpt": "Excerpt of review",
    "content": "Content of Review",
    "dateCreated": "2016-07-01",
    "datePublished": "2016-07-14",
    "featureImage": {
      "sys": {
        "type": "Link",
        "linkType": "Asset",
        "id": "3RD_UNIQUE_ID"
      }
    }
  }
}
],
"includes": {
    "Asset": [
       {
         "sys": {
         "space": {
         "sys": {
             "type": "Link",
             "linkType": "Space",
             "id": "1ST_UNIQUE_ID"
         }
       },
       "id": "4TH_UNIQUE_ID",
       "type": "Asset",
       "createdAt": "2016-07-14T16:30:05.078Z",
       "updatedAt": "2016-07-14T16:30:05.078Z",
       "revision": 1,
       "locale": "en-US"
    },
    "fields": {
      "title": "Image Title",
      "description": "Image Description",
      "file": {
        "url": "//url-of-image.jpg",
        "details": {
          "size": 43098,
          "image": {
            "width": 1278,
            "height": 928
          }
        },
        "fileName": "image.jpg",
        "contentType": "image/jpeg"
      }
    }
  }
  ]
 }
 }
```

I assume by looking up the ID for the Item you need and then any relationships you get the ID of the Asset and then look in assets? But again is this done through the SDK? or do i need to write this code?

I'm lost...

any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I Work at contentful and I am responsible of the JS SDKs.

I can see few solutions here:

1. You can follow [this](https://github.com/contentful-labs/product-catalogue-web.ts) example built by us and continue from there, it is built on top of Angular, you might also need to update the dependencies etc... if you need any help feel free to create an issue there,
2. Using ngUpgrade you can make Angular 1 modules running on Angular 2 and vice versa more infos [here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/10/24/upgrading-apps-to-angular-2-using-ngupgrade.html) . That's a quick and dirty solution
3. You can fork the code and go through [Angular migration guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html)
4. You can use the contenful.js SDK and wrap it in a Service, there you will have the link resolution etc... and then populate your views

I can't provide you with the sample code right now but we are working on example projects using Angular 2 and other frameworks.

Please note that the repo you mentioned is not officially maintained by Contentful.

Best,
Khaled

Comment: Hey, any update on this? Are there any examples now?

Comment: there is a tutorial on how to do that https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/javascript/tutorials/using-contentful-in-an-angular-project/